# Overlaying and staggering two plots with different y axes

Tags: r, plot

I am looking for advice for plotting 2 similar wave forms with different y axes scales (one is mmHg and another is m/s) in the same plot. However, I would like to stagger the plots with respect to each other.

For example, using the below:

```
set.seed(123)  
y <- sin(2*pi*x)  
g <- sin(2*pi*x)+ rnorm(200, sd=0.1)

plot(y,type="l",
     ann = F,
     axes = F)  
axis(side = 2)  

par(new = T)

plot(g,type="l",
     ann = F,
     axes = F)  
axis(side = 4)
```

Gives:

[image: resultant plot]

I would like to achieve something like this (see link below):

[image: what I would like to achive]

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a slightly cheaty solution:

```
x <- seq(from = 1, to = 3, by = 0.01)
y <- sin(2*pi*x)  
set.seed(123)  
g <- sin(2*pi*x)+ rnorm(length(x), sd=0.1)

stagger <- 2
glabels <- c(-1, 0, 1)

plot(c(min(y),max(y)+stagger) ~ c(1,length(y)), type="n", axes=FALSE, ann=FALSE)
lines(y)
axis(side = 2, at = min(y):max(y))  

par(new = T)
lines(g+stagger)
axis(side = 4, at = glabels + stagger, labels = glabels)
```

Results in:[image]

There's probably a better way to generate the positions and labels for the y-axis for g.